# How to get byte array size of a canvas

Tags: html, image-processing, canvas

i am using the html5 canvas. I load an image onto it.

After much Googling I found this snippet:

```
                    c3.toBlob(function (blob) {
                        alert(blob.size);                       
                    });
```

//note c3 is my canvas element...

But I got an error of 'undefined'

Is there a way of reading the size of the byte array once the image is loaded?

Comment: @GameAlchemist Hi, thanks for your comment. I did spend some time Googling.  Plenty of options on server side but I wanted to check that the bytes rendered on client is equal to the bytes stored and sent via server.  I was performing a mental exercise that may or may not help me...

Comment: Your question needs more details. When you drawImage the image on the canvas, do you scale it or do you adjust canvas size to fit image size ? Show your code. If both img/cv sizes are equal, buffer size = 4 * number of pixels  = 4 * width * height . (r + g + b + a = 4 bytes / px ).  But if you send image as .jpg everything changes. You might read : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp / Pixel Manipulation . (true reference might be too harsh : http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation )

Comment: thank you for the info and links. I will read this now :)